# How to use perl's pack function to reorder fields

Tags: perl, pack, unpack

I'm trying to reorder fields when building a string using `pack`, but I can't seem to get `pack` to do what I want.  For example, I want to populate a string with `abc` at offset 12, `defg` at offset 8, and `hi` at offset 3 (and whatever, presumably space or `\0`, at offsets 0-2 and 5-7).

```
perl -e '
   use strict; use warnings;
   my $str = "...hi...defgabc";
   my $fmt = q{@12 a3 @8 a4 @3 a2};

   my @a = unpack $fmt, $str;
   print "<$_>\n" for @a;
   print "\n";

   print unpack("H*", pack($fmt, @a)), "\n";
'
```

This works fine for `unpack`ing fields in any order out of a string.  But for `pack`ing, it `\0`-fills and truncates as [documented](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html).  Is there any way to stop it from `\0`-filling and truncating without reordering the `pack` template to produce the fields left-to-right?

This question comes up when reading a field specification from an external source.  Of course it can be arranged for the `pack` template to be produced in left-to-right order and resulting list can be reordered to match the external field specification.  But it would sure be handy to reposition the `pack` "cursor" dynamically without filling in intermediate positions or truncating.

In the above code, I would be happy if the return value of `pack(...)` was the same as `$str` with any byte for `.` (e.g. blank or `\0`).

Comment: I don't think that `pack` can be made to simply honor what's in the string at those other positions, if that's what you mean. It concatenates.  It is the job of `substr` to do that (but with one at the time).

Comment: So what do you want to be at those other places, up to `3` and between `hi` and `8`?  The original parts of `$str`? Then what happens with those ranges that were unpacked -- do they also stay as they had been (so then they are duplicated in the output string)?

Comment: @zdim At this point I don't really care about the other positions.  The question is a general one about how to reorder the positions of the fields in the `pack` arguments per the pack template.  Of course it would be great to be able to blank or NUL them out by choice.

Comment: OK.  But, one has to choose what to do with them -- or, what do we write? If it's "re-order" that may imply that what was at `3-5` is now at `12-14` (and vice versa), and that is fine. Or, perhaps you want 'blank' (spaces) instead.  Do you take a 16-char long string to re-order, or do you pick elements from _a_ string and write out a 16-char long string, with the rest being .... zero? Spaces? NULL (gasp)?  There are nice solutions but it does matter what the whole job is. Or I may be completely misunderstanding it.  Can you post some input and output -- source and what you want to get?

Comment: @zdim See edits.  The input to `unpack` is `$str`.  The output to `pack` should be `$str` (or similar).

Comment: @zdim Maybe it's not clear, but `unpack` is parsing `$str` in **right-to-left** order instead of the usual left-to-right order.  That works fine.  But when I try to use `pack` to recreate the original `$str` by supplying the fields to be `pack`ed in, say, right-to-left order, the positioning format construct `@POS` which worked fine with `unpack` fails miserably to reproduce the same original `$str` value (or similar) with `pack`.

Comment: @JohnWiersba zdim's first comment is your answer: pack doesn't do that. If you amend your question to "how do I do this in perl?" there are of course many ways. Even ways that could key off of the pack template, if that's essential. But if the question is "how do I do this with pack?" the answer is "you don't" :)

Comment: @JohnWiersba  What I posted reflects my current understanding of what you are thinking about.  (It's `substr` functionality, if I am right.)  Writing in comments didn't make sense -- please let me know whether this addresses your quest and whether I can add some other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is no way for `pack` to do that directly.  Here is one way of doing it, which avoids looping and using `substr`.  However, compared with the easy comprehensibility of `unpack`ing, it's not very satisfactory.  I was hoping that I had misunderstood something in the `pack` documentation that would really allow `pack` to be the reverse of `unpack` for placement of fields within the `pack`ed string.

```
use strict; use warnings;
my $str = "...hi...defgabc";
my @pos = (
   { pos => 12, len => 3 }, 
   { pos =>  8, len => 4 }, 
   { pos =>  3, len => 2 }, 
);
my $fmt = join " ", map { "\@$_->{pos} a$_->{len}" } @pos;
# q{@12 a3 @8 a4 @3 a2};

my @a = unpack $fmt, $str;
print "<$_>\n" for @a;
print "\n";

my @sorted_idxes =
   sort { $pos[$a]{pos} <=> $pos[$b]{pos}
       or $pos[$a]{len} <=> $pos[$b]{len} }
   0..$#pos;

my $sorted_fmt = join " ", 
   map { "\@$pos[$_]->{pos} a$pos[$_]->{len}" } @sorted_idxes;

my $out = pack $sorted_fmt, @a[@sorted_idxes];
$out =~ s/\0/./g;
print "$out\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have [pack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) write at specific locations inside of a string. It doesn't move around a string with a "*cursor*" of sorts that can be repositioned -- but it rather just concatenates everything given to it and writes a new string with that.

> pack TEMPLATE,LIST
>   Takes a LIST of values and converts it into a string using the rules given by the TEMPLATE. The resulting string is the concatenation of the converted values. [...]

Further down the page, the docs also say

> You must yourself do any alignment or padding by inserting, for example, enough `"x"`es while packing. There is no way for `pack` and `unpack` to know where characters are going to or coming from, so they handle their output and input as flat sequences of characters.

You can, of course, write out the string in any way you want, but only by re-arranging your template (if attempted out of order it fills as necessary per `@`, going from zero and thus overwriting for each value), and writing out or filling the "*intermediate positions*" as well. So you can say

```
my $str = "...hi...defgabc";
my $fmt = q{@12 a3 @8 a4 @3 a2};

my @parts = unpack $fmt, $str;
# Add to @parts and template what need be in between or change $fmt to get all
my $res = pack "A3A4A2", @parts;
```

Then you could extract all parts of the original string, rearrange them or build a suitable index mask, and `pack` it. I understand that you know that and don't want it, but `pack` just can't do other than to write out the whole string.

As for writing parts of the string, this is precisely the job of [substr](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html). So perhaps you could write a little loop using `@fmt` and/or `@parts`, in which `substr` is going to replace sequences of given lengths at needed locations. However, `pack`-ing it all at once should be far more efficient.

Comment: Thanks, @zdim.  See my answer below for one way which avoids `substr` and looping.  I was hoping I was just missing something in the `pack` documentation, since `unpack` was so easy to use to extract fields using an out-of-order specification.

Comment: @JohnWiersba Nice, that's a kind of a thing I had in mind -- you can process things in many ways, and `join` and `map` are right for that kind of manipulations. I suggested `substr` to keep in line with your original idea, to efficiently write to parts of the string (it is very efficient). Also, given its syntax, it should be farily clean code. Or, since you were reaching for `pack`, to use it but will all parts, rearranged.  I can add these approaches to what I posted, if it's of some use.

Comment: @JohnWiersba  They aren't the same -- `unpack` starts with a string, and thus _can_ pull things out (while that's not its primary use). But `pack` has to write out a new string, and it has nowhere to go but to concat' all pieces that it's given.  The functionality you wanted is provided by `substr`.